# List zip files which have less than a specific number of files

Tags: command-line, files, unzip

I have thousands of `.zip` files in one folder. I wish to find which zip files have less than 15 files in them.

I know that `unzip -l` can list the contents of the zip files but I don't know how to create an output of zip files that have less than 15 files.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
for z in *.zip; do if (( $(unzip -l "$z" | sed -nr '$ s/.* ([0-9]+) files?/\1/p') < 15 )); then echo "$z"; fi; done
```

This lists the `.zip` files with less than 15 files to stdout (in the terminal), so if you want to create a list file, you can `tee` out or redirect. Here it is more readably, creating a list file at the end as well as printing in the terminal

```
for z in *.zip; do 
   if (( $(unzip -l "$z" | sed -nr '$ s/.* ([0-9]+) files?/\1/p') < 15 )); then 
      echo "$z"
   fi
done | tee small-zip-list
```

#### Notes

- `for z in *.zip` loop over files ending with `.zip` and do something to each one, represented by the variable `z` referenced with `$z`
- `if (( $(unzip -l "$z" | sed -nr '$ s/.* ([0-9]+) files?/\1/p') < 15 ))` make unzip count the files, extract the number from the output (there's surely a tidier way to extract only the number, but I know `sed` so I've used it - see [@muru's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/888083/list-zip-files-which-have-less-than-a-specific-number-of-files/888094?noredirect=1#comment1387707_888094) for a simpler way that may be faster with many files) and test whether it's less than 15, and if it is
- `echo "$z"` then print the filename
- `| tee small-zip-list` also print output to a new file, as well as in the terminal

Comment: Thank you @Zanna i tried to run the fires script and it always shows all the .zip filenames in the folder, even if i am decreasing the number form 15 to something smaller, it shows all the .zip files in the folder.

Comment: @yarone so sorry, I missed a space! I have fixed it now I hope, please try again

Comment: Might be slightly easier to use `zipinfo`: `zipinfo -1 foo.zip | wc -l` or `zipinfo -t foo.zip | awk '{print $1}'`

Comment: @yarone most welcome! :D

Comment: +1 Used one of the following: awk, sed, grep ;)

Answer (score 9):

Using **awk**:

```
for i in ~/path/to/your/folder/*.zip; do if (( $(unzip -l $i | awk 'END {print $(NF-1)}') < 15 )); then echo "$i"; fi; done
```

Or it can be also done with script.

Create script zip.sh

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for i in ~/path/to/your/folder/*.zip; do
    if (( $(unzip -l $i | awk 'END {print $(NF-1)}') < 15 )); then
        echo "$i"
    fi
done
```

Save it in home folder & Make it executable with `chmod +x zip.sh` and run from terminal `./zip.sh`

Here, `if (( $(unzip -l $i | awk 'END {print $(NF-1)}') < 15 ))`,

- `unzip -l $i` it will count the number of files from respective zip
  file & from its output,
- `awk 'END {print $(NF-1)}'` grep that count number only, if it is
  less than 15 then it will print the filename.

Answer (score 9):

A late python option, using `python`'s `zipfile`, (as suggested by @muru, thanks!)

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
from zipfile import ZipFile

dr = sys.argv[1]

for zp in [os.path.join(dr, f) for f in os.listdir(dr) if f.endswith(".zip")]:
    if len(ZipFile(zp, "r").namelist()) < int(sys.argv[2]):
        print(zp)
```

#### How to use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `get_zips.py`
2. Run it with the directory and the desired (minimum) number of files inside, e.g.:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/get_zips.py /full/path/to/directory_with_zips 15
   ```

#### Explanation

The script:

- lists `.zip` files inside a directory:

  ```py
  for zp in [os.path.join(dr, f) for f in os.listdir(dr) if f.endswith(".zip")]:
  ```
- Looks inside the file and counts the number of files:

  ```py
  if len(ZipFile(file, "r").namelist()) < n:
      print(file)
  ```

  Only prints the file(+path) if the number of listed items is smaller then `n`.

Comment: Python? [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html)!

Comment: @muru thanks again, that makes a difference :)

Answer (score 5):

Perl also has a package for handling zip archives, `Archive::Zip`. The script below takes zip files as command-line arguments and provides command-line output with name and count of files within archive.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Archive::Zip;

foreach (@ARGV){
    my $fh = Archive::Zip::->new();
    if (my $error = $fh->read($_)){
        die "Read error:" . $_;
    }
    if($fh->numberOfMembers() < 15 ){
        printf("%s\t%d\n",$_,$fh->numberOfMembers());
    }
}
```

Test run:

```
$ ./count_zip_contents.pl  *.zip                           
129804-findmac.py.zip   1
Re%3a_China_and_East_Asia_%5bHIS-1250-010_31616.201730%5d%3a_Team_up_for_East_Asian_History_class.zip   4
University_Formal_jpg&tif.zip   5
indicator-places-master.zip 4
lab 5.zip   8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for z in *.zip; do if (( $(unzip -Z1 "$z" | wc -l) < 15 )); then echo "$z"; fi;done
```

Comment: a minor change to @zanna's code "$(unzip -Z1 "$z" | wc -l )"

Answer (score 0):

Get total number of files using zipinfo:

```bsh
$ for f in *.zip; do \
  a=($(zipinfo -t "$f")); \
  (($a > 15)) && echo $f; done
```